# Currency format in php?

Tags: php

I am looking at the money_format function in php and confused on how to get it to format the way I want. I do not want USD in front of my string, I want to change  123 will be formated to 123.00

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use this `money_format("%!.2n", 123)` the ! suppresses the currency symbol from the output as it is written in the [documentation](http://de3.php.net/money_format) of `money_format`

Answer (score 1):

Or try `sprintf` [1] for example:

```
sprintf("%.2f", 123.1);
```

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$money = 123;

echo money_format( '%!#4.2i', $money );
```

To explain the format string:

- %, this is the required first character
- !, this suppresses the currency symbol,
- #4, this says we wil have a maximum of 4 digits on the left of the decimal and will right justify accordingly,
- .2, this specifies 2 decimal places,
- i, this is the required character specifying the conversion characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try number_format? http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php